# Clean up html output for anonymous users in SharePoint 2010

Tags: html, sharepoint, optimization, sharepoint-2010

I'm using SharePoint 2010 for building a large internet facing website and I am now in the process of optimising the site for anonymous users.
As I look in the html sourcecode of my start page I find that various ootb components of SharePoint are adding lots of unnecessary stuff to the page. (At least they are unnecessary to the anonymous user, since we are using completely custom branding.)

Some examples:

In head:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
.ctl00_PlaceHolderOuterWrap_DialogPlaceHolder_PlaceHolderOuterMain_TopWebPartZone_0 { border-color:Black;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid; }
.ctl00_PlaceHolderOuterWrap_DialogPlaceHolder_PlaceHolderOuterMain_LeftWebPartZone_0 { border-color:Black;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid; }
.ctl00_PlaceHolderOuterWrap_DialogPlaceHolder_PlaceHolderOuterMain_RightWebPartZone_0 { border-color:Black;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid; }
.ctl00_PlaceHolderOuterWrap_DialogPlaceHolder_PlaceHolderOuterMain_ctl01_SocialWebPartZone_0 { border-color:Black;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid; }
.ctl00_wpz_0 { border-color:Black;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid; }
```

In top of body:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
//<![CDATA[
var MSOWebPartPageFormName = 'aspnetForm';
var g_presenceEnabled = true;
var g_wsaEnabled = false;
var g_wsaLCID = 1033;
var g_wsaSiteTemplateId = 'XXX#1';
var g_wsaListTemplateId = 850;
var _fV4UI=true;var _spPageContextInfo = {webServerRelativeUrl: "\u002fen-gb", webLanguage: 1033, currentLanguage: 1033, webUIVersion:4,pageListId:"{28b31ecf-221c-4a5f-94e2-6b97af0cfd61}",pageItemId:1, alertsEnabled:true, siteServerRelativeUrl: "\u002f", allowSilverlightPrompt:'True'};//]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
<!--
var L_Menu_BaseUrl="/en-gb";
var L_Menu_LCID="1033";
var L_Menu_SiteTheme="";
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
//<![CDATA[
document.onreadystatechange=fnRemoveAllStatus; function fnRemoveAllStatus()    {removeAllStatus(true)};var _spWebPartComponents = new Object();//]]>
</script>
```

And lots of other stuff near the bottom of the page, such as javascript functions etc.

Anyone who has tried removing all of this stuff?

I'm looking for as clean way as possible, parsing the html in a http-module filter is not very appealing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion to remove as much clutter as possible is to use a dedicated master page for anonymous user (and remove all user / server controls that you don't need for them). You can have your page layout that implements a base class in which during the init phase you assign your own anonymous only master page.

An alternate solution is to wrap the web controls / components responsible for the clutter / uneeded html within an authenticated only control template.

```
/// <summary>
/// Base Abstract control for conditionally (permissions, querystring, audience, anonymous, etc.) visible content 
/// </summary>
[ParseChildren(true)]
public abstract class ConditionallyVisibleControl : Control
{
    public ITemplate ContentTemplate { get; set; }
    public abstract bool ShouldBeVisible { get; }

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        base.CreateChildControls();

        if (ShouldBeVisible && ContentTemplate != null)
        {
            Control container = new Control();
            ContentTemplate.InstantiateIn(container);
            Controls.Add(container);
        }
    }
}
```

and them have something like

```
/// <summary>
/// Hide some content to anonymous user
/// </summary>
/// <example>
///     <UC:AnonymousTrimmedControl runat="server">
///         <ContentTemplate>
///             <!-- Any content over there that will not be rendered / visible for anonymous users -->
///         </ContentTemplate>
///     </UC:AnonymousTrimmedControl>
/// </example>

public class AnonymousTrimmedControl : ConditionallyVisibleControl
{
    public override bool ShouldBeVisible
    {
        get
        {
            return (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a nice idea, though it will lead to extra maintenance in the form of dupliacte masterpages. I'll upvote it, but it does not really answer my question on how to get rid of the stuff...

Comment: You can have your authenticated master page inheriting / using your public one to avoid re-creating it from scratch on both side. And to get rid of the stuff, most of them are coming from the SharePoint web controls that you can dismiss / remove in the anonymous master page. An alternate solution would be to wrap them in authenticated only template controls. I'll update my reply above.

Comment: (by inherting I meant using the MasterPageFile attribute on the private one pointing to the one for the anonymous which would act as the base one.)

Comment: Hmm..I'll have to try that out. Unfortunately we have already gone live with the site and management is very touchy about major changes of this sort. I'll see if I can convince them to test it out.
My concern is that much of the "clutter" is caused by having a webpartmanager on the page, and I think I would have to have one of those even on my anonymous page...